# add rowsource to multicolumn Listbox in access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a form in Microsoft Acsess 2013 showing filtered records after selection by user.

I added a Listbox showing **different type** of ITEM. I managed to get the result by writing:

```sql
Listbox.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT ITEM FROM TABLE WHERE " & strUserInput
```

which strUserInput is the filter condition.

I searched up and down, tried Listbox.AddItem, set properties of Listbox (Row Source Type) to Value List, etc. But none of them is working. Can anybody show me how to **sum up** the quantity of each ITEM and **show** it at the second column of the Listbox? Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the issue might be how Listbox works in general. The RowSourceType property specifies how you are supplying the data to the Listbox (Table/Query, Value List (a delimited list of values, etc.) Changing this property alone will not solve your problem.

What you want, I suspect, is a multi-column Listbox. You will need to specify the Column Count property and will need to supply the data for both columns either as part of your query or via a Value List.

Working from your example, I suspect it might be easiest to leverage a query like the following:

```
SELECT PART_TYPE_CODE AS [PART TYPE CODE], Count(*) AS [QTY] FROM [PART TRANSACTION HISTORY Query] WHERE " & strUserInput & " GROUP BY PART_TYPE_CODE"
```

This assumes of course that the `[PART TRANSACTION HISTORY QUERY]` contains the necessary data you want to aggregate